# Android: "ant emma debug install" not working properly

Tags: java, android, testing, ant, junit

I'm trying to create a code coverage report for Android JUnit Test. I intend to use EMMA for this. I tried to use the following steps using commandline:

1st - Build the application project with
      "D:\SupportWork\ProjectA>android update project -p . -t android-19 --subprojects"

2nd - Build the test-project with
      "D:\SupportWork\TestProjectA>android update test-project -m ..\ProjectA -p ."

3rd - Test if I can build the application project with
      "ant emma clean debug"

4th - Try to do the test in the test-project with
      "ant emma clean debug install test"

In the 4th step is the part I got stuck. My cmd says in the install part

```
install:
     [echo] Installing D:\SupportWork\TestProjectA\bin\ProjectATest-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
     [exec] rm failed for /data/local/tmp/ProjectATest-debug.apk, No such file or directory
     [exec] protocol failure
```

I basically have 2 projects. The Application Project and a Test Project as follows:

1. App Project  - D:\SupportWork\ProjectA
2. Test Project - D:\SupportWork\TestProjectA

Application Project's Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testsample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testsample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Application Project's local.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=C:\\Android\\sdk
```

Application Project's project.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
```

Application Project's build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MainActivity" default="help">

    <!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
         It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
         Version Control Systems. -->
    <property file="local.properties" />

    <!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
         'android' tool to add properties to it.
          This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
         Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

         source.dir
             The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
         out.dir
             The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

         For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
         files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

         Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
         be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

         -->
    <property file="ant.properties" />

    <!-- if sdk.dir was not set from one of the property file, then
         get it from the ANDROID_HOME env var.
         This must be done before we load project.properties since
         the proguard config can use sdk.dir -->
    <property environment="env" />
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
    </condition>

    <!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
         tool, as well as ADT.

         This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
         dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
         (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

    <!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />

    <!--
        Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
        This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
            -pre-build
            -pre-compile
            -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                           Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                           If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
            -post-package
            -post-build
            -pre-clean
    -->
    <import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

    <!-- Import the actual build file.

     To customize existing targets, there are two options:
     - Customize only one target:
         - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
           <import> task.
         - customize it to your needs.
     - Customize the whole content of build.xml
         - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
           into this file, replacing the <import> task.
         - customize to your needs.

         ***********************
         ****** IMPORTANT ******
         ***********************
         In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
         in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
        -->
    <!-- version-tag: 1 -->
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

</project>
```

Test Project's Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testsample.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.testsample" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Test Project's local.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=C:\\Android\\sdk
```

Test Project's project.properties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
```

Test Project's build.xml

```
<!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
     It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
     Version Control Systems. -->
<property file="local.properties" />

<!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
     'android' tool to add properties to it.
     This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
     Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

     source.dir
         The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
     out.dir
         The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

     For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
     files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

     Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
     be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

     -->
<property file="ant.properties" />

<!-- if sdk.dir was not set from one of the property file, then
     get it from the ANDROID_HOME env var.
     This must be done before we load project.properties since
     the proguard config can use sdk.dir -->
<property environment="env" />
<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>

<!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
     tool, as well as ADT.

     This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
     dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
     (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

<!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
<fail
        message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
        unless="sdk.dir"
/>

<!--
    Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
    This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
        -pre-build
        -pre-compile
        -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                       Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                       If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
        -post-package
        -post-build
        -pre-clean
-->
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

<!-- Import the actual build file.

     To customize existing targets, there are two options:
     - Customize only one target:
         - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
           <import> task.
         - customize it to your needs.
     - Customize the whole content of build.xml
         - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
           into this file, replacing the <import> task.
         - customize to your needs.

     ***********************
     ****** IMPORTANT ******
     ***********************
     In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
     in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
    -->
    <!-- version-tag: 1 -->
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

</project>
```

Test Project's ant.properties

```
# This file is used to override default values used by the Ant build system.
#
# This file must be checked into Version Control Systems, as it is
# integral to the build system of your project.

# This file is only used by the Ant script.

# You can use this to override default values such as
#  'source.dir' for the location of your java source folder and
#  'out.dir' for the location of your output folder.

# You can also use it define how the release builds are signed by declaring
# the following properties:
#  'key.store' for the location of your keystore and
#  'key.alias' for the name of the key to use.
# The password will be asked during the build when you use the 'release' target.

tested.project.dir=..\\ProjectA
```

Any ideas? I am using an AVD. I use Android-19 and Jdk 1.7 in my JAVA_HOME

I checked the D:\SupportWork\TestProjectA\bin and the ProjectATest-debug.apk is there but in /data/local/tmp it is not there...I thought we can choose to use an emulated device so there are no longer any "rooted device" related issue. Is there anything I am missing?

I searched this all around the net for this specific problem for a week now and I still have not yet found one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to drop the clean in the 4th step?

Comment: Hi, yes, it is still the same

Comment: install:
     [echo] Installing D:\SupportWork\TestProjectA\bin\MainActivityTest-debug.apk onto default emulator or device..
     [exec] rm failed for /data/local/tmp/MainActivityTest-debug.apk, No such file or directory
     [exec] protocol failure

BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1364: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:1378: exec returned: 1

Comment: The link I based is from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project although I am not using jenkins and I am trying to run this only on cmd for now

Comment: Can you post example projects that you are trying to test with emma?
Also copy the content of project.properties files.

Comment: I updated to add the Properties files of the dummy project and test-project I created

Comment: Do you have ant.properties file for test project?

Comment: Yes, It is the "Test Project's ant.properties" at the bottom portion of this post

Comment: Try adding this to test's ant.properties: test.runner=com.zutubi.android.junitreport.JUnitReportTestRunner

Comment: Same thing:

install:
     [echo] Installing D:\SupportWork\TestProjectA\bin\MainActivityTest-debug.apk onto default emulator or device..
     [exec] rm failed for /data/local/tmp/MainActivityTest-debug.apk, No such file or directory
     [exec] protocol failure

Answer (score 0):

Try `ant clean emma debug`, hope this would probably help.

Comment: (This might be better a comment, but in case it works I guess the original poster will adjust the wording before accepting. To me it looks more just like an option to grab more info to find the cause of the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer and comments guys, apparently, the only reason it wasn't working properly is because the computer I was using was blocking any read/write access via to the device so that's why it wasn't working properly.